# How to stop leakage of mains adaptor

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, mains, leakage-current

For the past year or so I have been using a mains to 5VDC adaptor to charge various devices. Everything is working perfectly fine but this charger I think, has a noticable leak to the low voltage side because as i was touching a grounded metal plate with one hand and holding my mobile (which was being charged using this adaptor at the time) i felt a tingle on my hand.
Then i tried grabbing the lead connected to my mobile and touching it on the metal surface and i could see arcs. I compared that to my original Apple adaptor by doing the same thing, but there where no (visible) arcs.

I opened the non-original adaptor and I think it looks very well designed as it has a good seperation between HV and LV sides, a capacitor rated at 1KV with value 203 (0.02nf I think) between them, and also good isolation of components.

So i wanted to ask, what could I do to stop this leakage or at least minimise it?

Thank you!

Comment: Most adapters typically use a 1 nF, 1 kV capacitor instead of the (I think) 20 nF ! 203 would stand for 20000 pF which is 20 nF. That would explain the AC leakage. Do make sure you replace it with a proper 1 kV capacitor that also is of the right type, I mean it has to be **Y-rated**

Comment: @FakeMoustache Oh, I'll do that, thanks! I think your comment answers my question. Thank you!

Comment: @FakeMoustache Are the Y-rated caps usually the paper film type?

Comment: Paper film ? Hmm, that sounds oldfashioned to me. But it could be that its still used. Its also possible to make Y rated caps using (polymer ?) film, see http://powerblog.vicorpower.com/2013/06/what-are-y-capacitors/  Crucial is the failure mode of the cap. It has to remain open circuit (not short !) when it fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switching supplies of this type usually have a capacitor between primary and secondary for EMI reasons: -

[image]

Notice C11 (220 pF) above the transformer at the top. This gives you the slight tingle and you should not consider replacing it unless you know what you are doing. You can double check things though.

You should measure the current with a meter to check that it is OK i.e. 1 mA or under does not pose a problem for anyone. A 10 nF capacitor at 50 Hz has 318 kohm impedance and from a 230 V AC supply could produce a current of about 0.7 mA. Anything significantly higher than this and I would worry about the supply. A 203 capacitor sounds like a 20 nF capacitor and this would potentially be able to source about 1.5 mA. It's probably still OK but if you are getting contradictory results between measurements and component values I'd consider replacing the device.

The other thing to do is check if the device should be earthed and convince yourself it is getting an earth via the plug. Chances are it doesn't require an earth but it's not unheard of things like this going wrong.

Play safe.

Comment: For class I products (grounded), you are allowed to leak 750 uA according to IEC 60950 and 250 uA for class II (non grounded, double insulated) products. 1 mA won't kill you, but it's very unpleasent.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately my multimeter died recently (accidentally exposed it to 7KV which fried the chip..) so it will take some time for the new one to arrive. Ill make sure to measure it though! I think i might buy a Y class capacitor of 1nf as it was recomended on the comments of my initial post above^ and replace it. Would that have any other consequence? Lastly, i recently bought a 99p mains to 5VDC adaptor for a project of mine, and since i needed the bare circuit, i realized that it doesnt have a capacitor across the two windings at all! Under what conditions can i use it?

Comment: I can't recommend you replace the capacitor at all. I can't state any conditions in which the 99p adapter can be used because I know nothing about it.